# How can I store large binary objects in azure sql db?

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure

I have a local ASP.NET web site (database contains some pictures as binary objects) that I want deploy to Azure web services. How can I store pictures in Azure SQL DB?
I'm trying this query, but..
[image: query]

Is there another way to keep large binary object in Azure DB? Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Off topic comment ... I would recommend storing these images in blob storage instead of SQL DB and store their URL in DB.

Comment: +1 to Gaurav's point.  Here's a good tutorial on how to do it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: I'm already refactored my DB to storing images as links! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use other way to do that. You can use **SqlStream class written in C# code**.

because bulk insert is not permit in sql database.

check these link, that have a way to do that:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/streaming-blobs-to-and-from-sql-azure/

Comment: I checked this link earlier but I can't compile this example cause of an [error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90254390/error.png) ('SqlStream' is inaccessible due to its protection level). I really don't understand why that